# Why has my account been suspended on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, account-suspension

My account was OK one day before yesterday, but now when I try to open it, why does it show the message that the account has been temporarily suspended?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with your last two questions, both requiring moderator intervention.  Put your email address in your profile so moderators can contact you.

Comment: I have already added my email address

Answer (score 8):

I'm not the one who suspended you, but I see the reason and also that a notification was never sent out.  I just sent a private message to your account on SO explaining the reason.  Sorry for the skipped notification earlier.

Comment: Can you send a private message to me so I can see what they look like?  I'm curious.

Comment: @jinguy The message says "YOU are curious"

Comment: @jjnguy: I would but it sends a copy to all moderators on the site, and Jeff already asked us to cut back on how much we're using it (basically to stop spamming him).  He added a big red message at the top of the UI.  "Privately contacting individual users should be reserved for VERY serious moderation issues only! If you need to communicate with a user for more typical issues, do so by leaving a comment on their posts, where other users can potentially benefit from it."

Comment: @Bill, so you are saying I should start causing **serious** trouble! `:P`

Comment: @jjnguy: I was going to ask for the names of your sock puppet accounts, but I knew you wouldn't fall for it.  ;)

Comment: the sad truth is that suspending users for quality is no longer notable or interesting, and happens pretty much on a daily basis. IMHO.

Comment: I learn something every day here.... today's lesson: SO **does have** private messages! :D

Comment: @Jeff: Do you think you could add a short reason (maybe link it to a longer explanation) to the "This account is temporarily suspended." message in user's profiles?  That would make the notification that goes out to every site moderator optional.

Comment: @bill it links to the blog post which has a good and recently updated explanation. I am open to hearing ideas for edits to make that blog post better.

Comment: @Jeff: I was thinking of a more specific page based on the message templates you have set up, but I guess the blog post does already cover the two most common cases for boxing.  If they can't figure out which category they fall in, then a more explicit message probably isn't going to help anyway.